# php: Save the entire $_POST variable in the session

Tags: php, session, post

Is this valid:

```
$_SESSION['pictures']['rateAlbum']['_POST'] = $_POST;
```

I want to save all of the POST data in the session in one shot.

edit:
oh and what about the other way around:

```
$_POST = $_SESSION['pictures']['rateAlbum']['_POST'];
```

Comment: you can do it, but you may be begging for some debugging nightmares down the road.  I'm going to guess that you're trying to do something like preserve form state after showing errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can...
if you save `$_POST` in `$_SESSION` in session you'll have the same array as post...

You can also do the other way and save something to `$_POST`..

you can also do that (or, using `$_SESSION`):

```
   $_POST = array('field1' => 'val1',
       'field1' => 'val1',
       'field1' => 'val1',
       'fieldn' => 'valn');        
   $_SESSION=$_POST;
```

or

```
   $test="hi";
   $_SESSION['field1']="test";
   echo $$_SESSION['field1']; //this print hi
```

PHP is really flexible and let you do almost everthing, obviously pay attention on security problem...

Answer (score 1):

you can use directly write below

```
$_SESSION['input_array']=$_POST[];
```

and if your `$_POST['username']='Hello';`
 then `$_SESSION['input_array']['username']` would display 'hello'
 and if `$_POST['birthday']['year']='2002'` then 
`$_SESSION['input_array']['birthday']['year']` would display 2002

Comment: Assume we're not using this $_POST or $_SESSION to access a database query (SQL Injection) or output data (XSS) is there anything they can $_POST that becomes a security issue? This is a real question as I've not seen anything about how maybe the PHP core can be compromised by blindly setting $_POST variables as a $_SESSION['somevar'] = 'somevalue' -> unless they can trigger an EXEC or something.

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST)`  RECURSIVELY before assigning it to $_session