# Post information from 1st page to 3rd page

Tags: php, post

I need to consider something in the future after I finish my application. What is going to happen is that a teacher will need to first login (login page is page 1), after login the page will go straight to a menu where the teacher selects a hyperlink link to open up a page (hyperlink menu is page 2), On third page I want a message displaying welcome to the teacher who has accessed the page (page 3 is welcome page).

Is there a way to get the teacher username from page 1 and displaying it on page 3 is what I am asking?

Below is coding and example:

Page 1: InputTest.php

```
<body>
    <form action="InputTest2.php" method="post">
    <p>Please enter your name</p><p><input type="text" name="user" /></p> 
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p> 
    </form>
    <!-- The above allows a name to be entered and submitted to "InputTest2" by clicking on send button -->
</body>
```

Page 2: InputTest2.php

```
<body>
    <p><a href="InputTest3.php">Welcome</a></p> 
    <p><a href="...">...</a></p> 
    <p><a href="...">...</a></p> 
</body>
```

Page 3: InputTest3.php

```
<body>
    <?php print "Welcome  <b>".$_POST['user']."</b><br/>\n"; ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your InputTest2.php 
add the following code in the start of the page

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['usernameLogged'] = $_POST['user'];
```

and then you can print it like this 
also you should start a session

```
<?php
session_start(); 
print "Welcome  <b>".$_SESSION['usernameLogged']."</b><br/>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Save it in the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
```

Then `$_SESSION['user']` will be available on the third page.

**Note:** you will need to have `session_start();` on both pages in order to store/retrieve session data like that.

---

Possible duplicate of: [php: Save the entire $_POST variable in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429896/php-save-the-entire-post-variable-in-the-session)

Comment: Note that you have to call `session_start()` on both pages.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I should have mentioned that, if OP is unaware of the SESSION then chances are he's missing `session_start()` in the first place. Thanks